# Scroll vertically and Horizontally with a rotating knob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have done a lot of research on this but unfortunately don't even really know where to begin. I have two knobs that rotate around 360 degrees using a plugin (knobKnob.jquery.js).

My goal is such that when I rotate the respective knobs I can scroll a specific div horizontally and vertically.

The plugin is pretty bulky so I can't really show it all here. My goal would be to have HTML5 and CSS3 rotating knobs but I have been unable to figure this out. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a cool-looking plugin so I decided to give it a whirl. [This page has everything to get started](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/pretty-switches-css3-jquery/). Unfortunately I can't get the last bit of the implementation correct, as the 100% turn will not scroll all the way right/down. (it has nothing to do with KnobKnob, more to do with my inability to grasp scrolling and element dimensions)

I give up and I'll leave that to you and more clever readers to figure out :) Maybe it has to do with the thicknesses of the scrollbars.

[**See the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XrVF8/4/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#control').knobKnob({
        snap: 10,
        value: 0,
        turn: function(ratio) {
            $("#ratio").val(ratio);
            $("#frame").scrollLeft(($("#frame")[0].scrollWidth - $("#frame").innerWidth()) * ratio);
        }
    });
    $('#control2').knobKnob({
        snap: 10,
        value: 0,
        turn: function(ratio) {
            $("#ratio2").val(ratio);
            $("#frame").scrollTop(($("#frame")[0].scrollHeight - $("#frame").innerHeight()) * ratio);
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: @Jason Thanks! It's a worthy plugin in my opinion :)

Comment: @MaryAnne Thank you very much! This was exactly the help I needed and I was able to resolve my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @Johan You're welcome! If you have a moment, do explain to me what you did to get the full turn to scroll all the way down. How did you fix my scrollHeight measurements?